# tsconfig.json honoring baseUrl absolute imports only some of the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, package.json, tsconfig

My `create-react-app` honors absolute imports in *some* files but not in others.

## Folder Structure

```
.
+-- tsconfig.js
+-- package.json
+-- src
|   +-- components
|   |   +-- ui
|   |   |   +-- Button
|   |   |   |  +-- Button.tsx
|   |   |   +-- Card
|   |   |   |  +-- Card.tsx
|   +-- pages
|   |   +-- Home.tsx
|   +-- index.tsx
```

## tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
}
```

If I import a `Button` from the `Home.tsx` file it works as expected:

**Home.tsx**

```js
import Button from 'components/ui/Button/Button.tsx'
console.log(Button)
```

(The `Button` logs in the console normally.)

**Card.tsx**

However, if I try and import `Button` from `Card.tsx` then it errors out.

```js
import Button from 'components/ui/Button/Button.tsx'
console.log(Button)
```

## Error

```
FAIL Failed to compile
./src/components/ui/Card/Card.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components' in '/Users/ninja/Desktop/Projects/My Apps/app-one/src/components/ui/Card/Card.tsx'
```

I have spent hours researching similar situations and experimenting with many combinations of `baseUrl`, `include`, and other `tsconfig.json` configurations but **cannot figure out what's wrong!** Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `tsconfig.json` is not properly structured (based on your sample of it you're not doing it right or you haven't posted the whle `tsconfig.json` file) or it's not in the right place.

1. Put `tsconfig.json` in the root folder of your project (same like as `package.json`)
2. Make sure you have your `tsconfig.json` structured like this:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Pay attention to the position of `"include"`. It's not on the same level like `"baseUrl"`

Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-typescript-forked-absolute-paths-stackoverflow-9jtqe?file=/src/index.tsx) I made for you based on your project's folder/file structure.

**NOTE:** One last thing. I'm being warned by linter that `An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing 'components/ui/Card/Card' instead.ts(2691)`... Meaning that you should remove `.tsx` extension from import path too.